# Java netbeans Jtable binding with database using the where clause

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, nimbus

So I have created an application featuring a table that is bound to a database. However I can not figure out how to add a where clause (So that you will only find transactions that are currently going on, any transactions that are finished are not supposed to be shown. I essentially want to make it show the rows only  when "Transactionstate='ongoing'" So i want to sort the rows so I won't see any rows that fit this criteria.

Here is a picture of my application with the table netbeans binded to my database.

[image: An image of the application with the table]

The table I am using is a JTable from the drag and drop menu in Netbeans design.

[image]

I did see that it is possible to manually create a table that can do what I am doing. But is there any other way to do this with Netbeans ? Or is there something I could download like the JCalendar ?

Please forgive me if this was an easy question...I am learning Java atm.

Sincerly..

//Orville Nordström

Comment: Please forgive me if this was an easy question == 1. read Oracle tutorial How to use Tables, 2. daily asked questions about JTable + JDBC, part of  JCalendars has own TableCellEditor/Renderer in API

Comment: Well I couldn't see anywhere where it said how to add the where clause...

Comment: [to add the where clause...???](http://java2s.com/Code/SQL/CatalogSQL.htm) or [to add the where clause...???](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Well I already know how to use SQL language. But i want to find some way to bind a netbeans table to a database, while I use a where clause (So that a JTable in netbeans design will only show all the rows where user = "user" or state=1. I want to add a condition like that to the netbeans table binding process.

Comment: sorry really I' don't know how GUI builder/designer works

Comment: On np thanks for attempting to give me guidance : ) But I really wish I could get an answer to this problem...I really don't understand why you can't add a where clause in Netbeans GUI builder...